# Parsing leetcode question content with requests and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to parse the content of the interview questions on Leetcode.

For example, on https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/,

I am trying to get

```
Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.

You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.
```

It didn't seem that hard. I used requests and BeautifulSoup to do it:

```
    url = 'https://leetcode.com/graphql/two-sum'
    try:
        page = requests.get(url)
    except (requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout,requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout):
        print('time out')
        return 'time out'

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    print(soup.prettify())
```

However, as you can see in the response of the page on the page through developer console (F12), the response does not include the content shown on the page.

Is there a way to get this content?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need selenium. The page does a POST request for dynamic content. Basically, sends a MySql query to a backend database. So, it is much quicker to do the following:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

data = {"operationName":"questionData","variables":{"titleSlug":"two-sum"},"query":"query questionData($titleSlug: String!) {\n  question(titleSlug: $titleSlug) {\n    questionId\n    questionFrontendId\n    boundTopicId\n    title\n    titleSlug\n    content\n    translatedTitle\n    translatedContent\n    isPaidOnly\n    difficulty\n    likes\n    dislikes\n    isLiked\n    similarQuestions\n    contributors {\n      username\n      profileUrl\n      avatarUrl\n      __typename\n    }\n    langToValidPlayground\n    topicTags {\n      name\n      slug\n      translatedName\n      __typename\n    }\n    companyTagStats\n    codeSnippets {\n      lang\n      langSlug\n      code\n      __typename\n    }\n    stats\n    hints\n    solution {\n      id\n      canSeeDetail\n      __typename\n    }\n    status\n    sampleTestCase\n    metaData\n    judgerAvailable\n    judgeType\n    mysqlSchemas\n    enableRunCode\n    enableTestMode\n    envInfo\n    libraryUrl\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n"}

r = requests.post('https://leetcode.com/graphql', json = data).json()
soup = bs(r['data']['question']['content'], 'lxml')
title = r['data']['question']['title']
question =  soup.get_text().replace('\n',' ')
print(title, '\n', question)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to load java scripts in page and then get page content. The easiest way to do this is by using Selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
import os


# initialise browser
browser = webdriver.Chrome(os.getcwd() + '/chromedriver')
# load page
browser.get('https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/')

# execute java script
browser.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML")

# wait page to load
sleep(5)

# get selected content
problem_description = browser.find_element_by_class_name('question-content__JfgR')
print(problem_description.text)
```

Output:

```
Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.
You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.
Example:
Given nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 9,

Because nums[0] + nums[1] = 2 + 7 = 9,
return [0, 1].
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. If I print `problem_description`, I get `<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="954ce2a379054a7b4f6657029fd05d82", element="0fadcc75-a463-4f14-b61b-5887ef70716e")>`. How did you retrieve the Output?

Comment: @Dawn17 you need to get properly version of you selenium webdriver from: http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: I am already using the right version for my chrome version. I don't think that is an error, but maybe a wrong way to retrieve the output, am I wrong?

Comment: @Dawn17 i updated my code with line of text printing: print(problem_description.text)

Comment: Nice! I didn't put the `.text`. Thanks a lot. This really helped!

Answer (score 0):

The website is generated by executing dynamic Javascript. So you won't get it simply using `requests`. You could use [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io) to simulate a Firefox browser.

Check the [tutorial](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html).

Comment: That's right. The website uses ReactJS to render pages to DOM. You need to simulate the browser and then get the data. Use selenium to render the DOM and then scrape data. OR checkout https://webscraper.io/